# finding the time difference for a string

Tags: python, string, datetime

In the below string

```
user: root sjc-array109-MGMT "nsstats  --var ds:diag:writeAdmitThrottleCount --from 2020-02-20,10:33:42 --to 2020-02-20,10:37:42 --interval 1 --diff
```

I need to find the time difference

i.e difference between the values 10:33:42 to 10:37:42

Comment: Parse both dates (regex), convert to datetime, substracting one datetime with another gives you third datetime that holds difference.


P.S. In SO we try to help and guide you, not doing work for you, so please, add specific questions and/or information, like what you tried, what exactly do you don't understand etc.

Comment: Give more details; Will the format of the string always be the same? will "--from" always precede "--to"? is it a 24-hour format of 12-hour format time? 
You can simply use regex if so.

Comment: the format of the string will always be the same  and the format is 24 hours

Answer (score 0):

Parse it as `datetime`, then just calculate difference (`datetime` supports subtraction):

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
date_from = parse('2020-02-20,10:33:42'.replace(',', ' '))
date_to = parse('2020-02-20,10:37:42'.replace(',',  ' '))
diff = date_to - date_from
print(diff.total_seconds())
```

Result: 240.0

I used `.replace` because `dateutil` recognises common datetime formats - but the comma inside is not a standard. You can also use [your own time formatter with `datetime.strptime` (click for documentation)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) .

---

**EDIT** For finding the dates in the string itself: since the dates don't have spaces in them and I'm lazy, quick solution not requiring regex:

```
s = 'user: root sjc-array109-MGMT "nsstats  --var ds:diag:writeAdmitThrottleCount --from 2020-02-20,10:33:42 --to 2020-02-20,10:37:42 --interval 1 --diff ...'
s = s.split()
d = dict(zip(s, s[1:]))

date_from = parse(d['--from'].replace(',', ' '))
date_to = parse(d['--to'].replace(',', ' '))

diff = date_to - date_from
print(diff.total_seconds())
```

Why this lazy solution works:

The dates don't have spaces in them, so `.split()` (by default splitting on whitespace) doesn't break the date. We know there's `--from` somewhere followed by its date and `--to` somewhere followed by its date.

`zip` makes the tuples of 1st elements from both iterables, 2nd elements... and so on. I used `[1:]` to make a copy without first element. Thus we now have pairs of 1st+2nd elements, 2nd+3rd, 3rd+4th...

Thus we know we have somewhere pairs containing `--from`+its date, and `--to`+its date.

So we should look for it. But again, I'm lazy, I don't want to do this manually (in a loop). So I made a dictionary - dictionary made from list of pairs, takes 1st elements of the pair as the key and the second element as the value.

Then we just look up our values - first elements were `--from` and `--to`, so they are the keys now.

Comment: is it possible for you to let me know the regular expression for finding the string between "--from"  to the "--interval"

Comment: Added something even better than regex that will work with `--from` and `--to` at any position in the string. Being lazy has its perks - you can find easier solution. :D

Comment: Thank you and i am new to python and sure will learn more on it and wont be lazy

Comment: I didn't mean you're lazy, I said my solution and I were! Because there's always a brute (straightforward, manual, thus quite universal) way to do it and a smart (lazy because less coding and testing, sometimes requires some explaining, uses problem-specific details to your advantage) way to do it. The more you learn, the more of those "lazy" (smart) solutions you will actually use - because Python syntax encourages that with its functional elements!